# How to send variables from one class to another.

Tags: java, class, variables, constructor

Hopefully it's not too late for someone to help me out. I'm trying to create a program that has one class (TestCode) that asks the user to enter 4 integers. Then, I send the variables from that class to another class (MySmartDataType). Then, I use those integers to perform certain calculations. The problem is, I'm not sure how to get the second program to accept those integers properly. Here is the first class.

```
import java.util.*;

class TestCode{

 public static void main(String args[]){
    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 0;
    int n3 = 0;
    int n4 = 0;

      String repeat = "Y";

    int evenTotal = 0;
    int oddTotal = 0;

    MySmartDataType msdt;       
    Scanner sc;
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      while (repeat == "Y"){

            System.out.println("Enter number 1 ");       
            n1 = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter number 2 ");       
            n2 = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter number 3 ");       
            n3 = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter number 4 ");       
            n4 = sc.nextInt();


                 System.out.println("Would you like to continue? N for no and Y for Yes.");
                 repeat = sc.nextLine();

                 msdt = new MySmartDataType(n1,n2,n3,n4);

                 }

            evenTotal = msdt.getEvenTotal();
            System.out.println("Even total is: " + evenTotal);

            oddTotal=  msdt.getOddTotal();
            System.out.println("Odd total is: " + oddTotal);               
            System.out.println("Grand Total is: " + msdt.getTotal() );                                              
}
}
```

And here's the second one:

```
import java.util.*;

class MySmartDataType {

private int myArray[] = new int [4];

myArray[4] = {n1, n2, n3, n4};

int getEvenTotal(){
int sumEven = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++){
    if (myArray[i] % 2 == 0){
    sumEven += myArray[i];
    }
} 
System.out.println("The even total is: " + sumEven);

return sumEven;
}

int getOddTotal(){
int sumOdd = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++){
    if (myArray[i] % 3 == 0){
    sumOdd += myArray[i];
    }
} 
System.out.println("The odd total is: " + sumOdd);

return sumOdd;

}

int getTotal(){
int sumTotal;

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    sumTotal += myArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The total is: " +sumTotal);

return sumTotal;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the variables globally then create getter, setter for the declared variables. So you can get the variable's value in any other class you want by getter method.

Answer (score 2):

Do a setter and getter method in order to get the variable to the other class.

Here is a tutorial on how to do it:

[YOUTUBE link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wF18uVxjtvc)

Answer (score 0):

Using `public static` modifier.

Example: `public static int example`, now you can using `example` in other class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your `MySmartDataType` class. Create 4 instance variables in your `MySmartDataType` which can hold the data being sent from other class.(eg: int var1...)

```
MySmartDataType(int num1,int num2,int num3,int num4)
{
var1 = num1;
var2 = num2;
var3 = num3;
var4 = num4;
}
```

Use var1...var4 in the methods to do the operations. You can replace var1...var4 with array, but then you need to loop every time to read the values and to do the opr's(which is not a bad option and up to you).

Answer (score 0):

You missed the constructor in MySmartDataType class. This constructor will be called when you create the object of this class in your first class; i.e.

```
msdt = new MySmartDataType(n1,n2,n3,n4);
```

the following doesn't make sense, remove it

```
myArray[4] = {n1, n2, n3, n4};
```

The constructor in MySmartDataType class will set the values to the array;

```
    public MySmartDataType (int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4) {
//this constructor will be called when the object of this class will be created with 4 integer parameters
      myArray[0] = n1;
      myArray[1] = n2;
      myArray[2] = n3;
      myArray[3] = n4;
    }
```

Comment: I got some of the errors off, but now I get these.

MySmartDataType.java:6: error: invalid method declaration; return type required

public MySmartDataType (int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4) { 
       ^

MySmartDataType.java:15: error: ';' expected

int getEvenTotal(){
                ^

MySmartDataType.java:27: error: ';' expected

int getOddTotal(){
               ^

MySmartDataType.java:40: error: ';' expected

int getTotal(){
            ^

4 errors

Comment: can you edit you question with the updated code you're trying now?

Answer (score 0):

I guess now you're learning OOP, right?
you can create some method with one or more parameters to fill your second class attributes.

for example :

```
function setData(int data, int pos){ myArray[pos] = data;}
```

and you can call that method from your first class

```
msdt.setData(something, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following constructor to the MySmartDataType class.

```
public MySmartDataType(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4)
{
    myArray = new int[]{n1, n2, n3, n4};    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
       import java.util.*;

      class MySmartDataType {

          private int myArray[] = new int [4];


          public MySmartDataType(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4) {
            myArray[0] = n1;
            myArray[1] = n2;
            myArray[2] = n3;
            myArray[3] = n4;
          }

         int getEvenTotal(){
         int sumEven = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++){
          if (myArray[i] % 2 == 0){
             sumEven += myArray[i];
           }
         } 
         System.out.println("The even total is: " + sumEven);

         return sumEven;
        }

       int getOddTotal(){
       int sumOdd = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++){
          if (myArray[i] % 3 == 0){
            sumOdd += myArray[i];
           }
        } 
       System.out.println("The odd total is: " + sumOdd);

       return sumOdd;

        }

        int getTotal(){
        int sumTotal = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
          sumTotal += myArray[i];
       }
        System.out.println("The total is: " +sumTotal);

       return sumTotal;
       }
```

}

Comment: Ok, that class is working now. But there's a weird error on the TestCode class: variable msdt might not have been initialized.

Comment: Assign null to `msdt` variable `MySmartDataType msdt = null;` in the TestCode class

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

```
package greetings;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Printer {

    @Inject @Informal Greeting greeting;

    private String name;
    private String salutation;

    public void createSalutation() {
        this.salutation = greeting.greet(name);
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }
}
```

Setters set a variable to your input parameters. Getters return the instance variable that one is "getting". For example,

```
Printer myobject = new Printer();
//sets instance variable 'name' to "Hello World"
myobject.setName("Hello World");
//gets instance variable 'name' with getter and sets it to mystring
String mystring = myobject.getName();
//will print "Hello World"
System.out.println(mystring);
```